# some doubts about noncommutative algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can someone tell me what's the appalication of the Rosenberg' method on the definition of 
the noncommutative algebraic geometry (left spectrum)?
    Now when talking about noncommutative algebraic geometry, we will follow the way of the 
category theory (abelian category, triangulated category and so on). What's the obstruction of the direct way from the algebraic geometry rather than the category theory? 
   For example, have someone studied or founded the theorem like Riemann-Roch theorem on the noncommutative schemes?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Also, what have you read about Rosenberg's method? Even on mathoverflow there are various good answers which explain it.

Comment: At the risk of being accused of self-promotion, if you're interested in obstruction results for noncommutative spectra, you can find one here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2239

Comment: As noncommutative spectra have structure stacks (and by evidence of plethora of other phenomena like the importance of bimodule morphisms) one should not expect 1-categorical functoriality, but at least a generalization like 2-categorical (pseudo)functoriality...

Comment: Your last sentence is discussed here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11746/is-there-grothendieck-riemann-roch-for-abelian-category or in brief, yes, in many settings. 

Comment: The answer to your first question can be found in Xin Tang's thesis, of which I do not have a link on hand(I'm typing on a phone). In short, the left spectrum was developed for purposes of application to representation theory. A natural place to look for a reference is the work of Rosenberg. In particular, his book from '95 uses the spectrum to consider representations of a certain class of algebras(those he refers to as hyperbolic algebras). Of course looking at the n-lab page on Rosenberg will provide you with many of his manuscripts of which many will answer you also. 

Comment: Along the lines of Javier's answer, I think the serious deficiency imposed by the lack of two-sided ideals is the difficulty in localization. A difficulty that can be overcome by passing to abelian(or Grothendeick) categories.

Answer (score 6):

Quick answer (to the second part): noncommutative rings don't have enough ideals to make a decent spectrum. In words of Fred van Oystaeyen: "*it doesn't matter how you try to define what is a point of a noncommutative space, you never have enough of them*". There were some attempts of following more classical lines in the late seventies and early-mid eighties (see papers by Van Oystaeyen, Verschoren, and many others) but eventually everybody agreed that a more abstract approach was needed to get meaningful geometric information.

Comment: what means "decent spectrum" ? 

Comment: @Alexander: "decent" is a synonyme for "nice", not a mathematical notion.

Comment: He possibly meant faithful enough to reconstruct the scheme back and specializing to commutative one for commutative ring. These are usual minimal requirements. 

Comment: As Zoran says, by "decent" I mean nice enough to allow us to jump back and forth between the ring and the spectrum. In the classical situation if $R$ is a (commutative) ring and $X = Spec(R)$ then one can recover $R$ as the ring of global sections of the structure sheaf. In the noncommutative case, for instance if $R$ is the Weyl algebra $k<x,y>/(yx-xy-1)$ the spectrum is reduced to a single point and the global sections are constant functions.

Comment: Weyl algebra is good example to make me doubt in "... you never have enough of them".
Recall this famous result by Hollands (?) Berest Wilson - you classify projective modules over Weyl and you get exactly C^2 - the same amount as in the commutative limit of Weyl e.g. C[x,y]... Moreover you event get Hilbert scheme i.e. glued points...

How to be with this ?

Comment: Weyl has more stuff in it than the commutative limit, since multiple non-abelian rings have the same abelianization.

Projective modules over a polynomial ring are free by Quillen-Suslin. Morevover, modules aren't ideals, and don't behave as such.

Comment: Indeed, modules have way more information than ideals. IIRC, one of the categorical approaches to NCAG (by Smith, Van den Berg and others) basically relies on considering certain categories that behave in a similar way to categories of modules and just go on as if they were the categories of quasi-coherent sheaves over a noncommutative space. I think that Smith published a paper defining "module points", "module lines" and the like, but cannot find it right now.