# How the existence of holomorphic sections depends on the choice of complex structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, line-bundles, flag-varieties

In this [Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215067/equivariant-almost-complex-structures-on-the-full-flag-manifolds) it is asked how many invariant complex structures exist on the full flag manifold of $SU(m)$. In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122401/classifying-globally-generated-holomorphic-line-bundles-over-a-flag-manifold) it is asked when a line bundle over a flag manifold has holomorphic sections. This caused me to think about how the existence of holomorphic sections depends on the choice of complex structure. I reason that it cannot be independent since, for complex projective space, a simple switching to the opposite complex structure will switch those line bundles with sections from positive to negative. Is these a neat answer here in general?