# Relationship between $q$-Weyl dimension formula and $q$-analog of weight multiplicity?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, q-analogs

$\DeclareMathOperator\dim{dim}$For a dominant (integral) weight $\lambda$ and any (integral) weight $\mu$ of a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, *Lusztig's $q$-analog of weight multiplicty* $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ is a $q$-analog of the dimension $\dim V^{\lambda}_{\mu}$ of the $\mu$-weight space $V^{\lambda}_{\mu}$ of the highest weight $\mathfrak{g}$-irrep $V^{\lambda}$ with highest weight $\lambda$. There are a few ways to define it, but probably the simplest is to think of it as the Hilbert series associated to a filtration on $V^{\lambda}_{\mu}$ induced by the action of any regular nilpotent element of $\mathfrak{g}$. See for instance [Lusztig's original paper "Singularities, character formulas, and a $q$-analog of weight multiplicities"](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AST_1983__101-102__208_0) and [Joseph, Letzter and Zelikson - "On the Brylinski–Kostant filtration"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2646135). In Type A, the $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ are called *Kostka–Foulkes polynomials* and sometimes this name is used in other types too.

(Other ways to define $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$: via a $q$-analog of Kostant's partition function; in terms of intersection cohomology of Schubert varieties; as certain affine Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomials.)

On the other hand, let us define the *$q$-dimension* of $V^{\lambda}$ to be $\dim_q(V^{\lambda}) \mathrel{:=} \sum_{\mu} (\dim V^{\lambda}_{\mu}) q^{\langle \mu, \rho^{\vee}\rangle}$, where $\rho^{\vee}$ is the dual of the Weyl vector $\rho$, which is the sum of the fundamental weights. I believe the Weyl character formula tells us that $\dim_q(V^{\lambda}) = \prod_{\alpha \in \Phi^+} \frac{[\langle\lambda+\rho,\alpha\rangle]_q}{[\langle\lambda,\alpha\rangle]_q}$, where $\Phi^+$ are the positive roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $[m]_q \mathrel{:=} \frac{(q^{1/2}-q^{-1/2})^m}{(q^{1/2}-q^{-1/2})}$. Maybe I'm slightly off here, but something more-or-less like this should be true, and I think the notion of *$q$-Weyl dimension formula* is anyways an established thing.

**Question**: what is the relationship between the $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ and $\dim_q(V^{\lambda})$? In particular, is there some way to write $\dim_q(V^{\lambda}) = \sum_{\mu} c_{\lambda,\mu}(q) K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ for some "simple" coefficients $c_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$?

Note that in Type A we have $s_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{\text{dominant $\mu$}} K_{\lambda,\mu}(q) P_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x})$, where $s_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x})$ is the Schur polynomial and $P_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x})$ is the [Hall–Littlewood polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93Littlewood_polynomials). And the $q$-Weyl dimension is essentially a principal specialization of $s_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x})$, and I believe the corresponding specialization of $P_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x})$ should give something like a $q$-binomial although I didn't fully work it out.

My main conceptual difficulty in linking $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ and $\dim_q(V^{\lambda})$ is that, for $\dim_q(V^{\lambda})$, each weight space contributes a single power of $q$, while for the $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ the weight spaces contribute many different powers of $q$.

But I still suspect something like what I'm asking for should be true and probably well-known, although I'm having trouble googling for the answer.

EDIT: I just noticed that in a comment to [this MathOverflow answer of Jim Humphreys](https://mathoverflow.net/a/31685/25028), Victor Protsak says "There is an interesting $q$-analogue of the character of a finite-dimensional module that involves the notion of $q$-multiplicity of weight due to Lusztig, and it specializes into a natural $q$-analogue of the Weyl dimension formula." An expansion of Victor's comment would likely answer my question.

Comment: For the coefficients $c_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$: I am happy to either sum over all $\mu$ or all dominant $\mu$. When $\mu$ is not dominant there are two different things $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ could mean: one is defined in terms of the $q$-Kostant partition function and is "bad" because it can have negative coefficients; the one I want is the one coming from the Brylinski-Kostant filtration. It is known that this second one is equal to $q^{\textrm{some explicit power}} \cdot K_{\lambda,\nu}(q)$ where $\nu$ is the dominant representative of $W\mu$ (see the  Joseph-Letzter-Zelikson paper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best reference for what I mention here is Stembridge's notes ["Kostka-Foulkes Polynomials of General Type"](https://www.aimath.org/WWN/kostka/stembridge.pdf). The picture you describe for type A actually generalizes nicely to all types.

Let's denote by $\Lambda$ the weight lattice, by $\Lambda^{+}$ the dominant weights, $W$ the Weyl group, and by $\chi_{\lambda}=\sum_{\mu} \dim(V^{\lambda}_{\mu})e^{\mu}$ the Weyl characters that live in the ring $\mathbb Z[\Lambda]^W$. There are Hall-Littlewood polynomials $P(\lambda,q)$ defined in the notes above, that satisfy the important identity
$$\chi_{\lambda}=\sum_{\mu\in \Lambda^+}K_{\lambda, \mu}(q)P(\mu,q) \tag{1}$$
In Lusztig's paper that you refer to, he proves this for one of the definitions of the $K_{\lambda,\mu}$ (Kazhdan-Lusztig for affine Weyl group) and states that conjecturally this is the same if one defines them by taking the q-analog of the Kostant's partition function (conjecture 9.6). This conjecture was proved by Kato in ["Spherical Functions and a q-Analogue of Kostant's Weight Multiplicity Formula"](https://eudml.org/doc/142892) using methods from spherical analysis on p-adic groups. A more elementary proof was given by R. K. Brylinski in ["Characters and the q-analog of weight multiplicity"](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-36.1.68).

In your question you want to take the principal specialization of $(1)$, so that $\chi_{\lambda}$ becomes $\operatorname{dim}_q(V^{\lambda})$. As a result, $c_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ becomes the principal specialization of the Hall-Littlewood polynomial $P(\mu,q)$. Just like in type A, this is always a nice q-product. In fact, this was one of the motivating examples behind the evaluation conjecture for Macdonald Polynomials (See conjecture 12.10 in Macdonald's ["Orthogonal polynomials associated with root systems"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011046), and the following discussion in (v) where it is explained that the principal specialization is known for the Hall-Littlewood case). The general principal specialization of Macdonald polynomials was proven later by Cherednik in ["Macdonald's Evaluation Conjectures and Difference Fourier Transform"](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9412016).

Comment: Thanks, especially for all the references; this is very illuminating.

Comment: Is it possible that the principal specialization of the $P(\mu,q)$ gives exactly the sum of all the $q^{\textrm{some explicit power}}$ (from my comment under the question) for the Weyl orbit of $\mu$? So that one could simply sum all the $K_{\lambda,\mu}(q)$ over all including non-dominant $\mu$ to get the $q$-Weyl dimension?

Comment: Disclosure of interest in this: Rhoades (https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2568) proved cyclic sieving results for both the Kostka-Foulkes polynomials (see also Fontaine-Kamnitzer https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.1314), and the $q$-Weyl dimension polynomials. But his method of relating the two results is kind of subtle. I was wondering if the Kostak-Foulkes result formally implies the $q$-Weyl dimension result.

Comment: @SamHopkins I haven't looked at Rhoades paper in a long time, but here are some superficial comments: In type A there are only so many natural candidates for q-analogs, so you will see $\frac{\text{q-thingy}}{\prod [h]_q}$ a lot. As Rhoades remarks, such expressions are $q$-dimensions but also Kostka-Foulkes polynomials. When you upgrade to the $q,t$-analogs you will see some expressions start to diverge, for example some $[h]_q$ will become $(1-q^at^{l+1})$ and some will be $(1-q^{a+1}t^l)$, similarly some expressions will start to diverge once you generalize outside of type A. [continued]

Comment: If anything, the main idea in these papers is that the Kazhdan-Lusztig theory is quite crucial to get these cyclic sieving results.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Well, so far... :)

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Yup, so far :) I think it would be very cool to have cyclic sieving of q-dimensions (especially in other root systems) that didnt rely on geometric interpretation of Kostka-Foulkes polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is $(8.10)$ of

Lusztig, George (1-MIT)
Singularities, character formulas, and a q-analog of weight multiplicities. Analysis and topology on singular spaces, II, III (Luminy, 1981), 208–229,
Astérisque, 101-102, Soc. Math. France, Paris, 1983.

available [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_1983__101-102__208_0.pdf)