# The Todd class and Weyl's character formula

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, differential-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional complex semi-simple Lie algebra. Fix a Cartan sub algebra $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ and let $R \subset \mathfrak{h}^{\ast}$ denote the root system. Choose a set of positive roots $R^+ \subset R$ and let $W$ denote the Weyl group. The Weyl character formula reads $$\text{Ch}(L(\lambda)) = \sum_{w \in W} \frac{(-1)^{\ell(w)} e^{w \cdot \lambda}}{\prod_{\alpha \in R^+} (1-e^{-\alpha})}.$$

Compare this with the Todd class of a complex vector bundle $\mathcal{E} \to M$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold. By pulling back, we can assume that $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{L}_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal{L}_n$ is a sum of line bundles. Set $\alpha_k : = c_1(\mathcal{L}_k)$ and define the Todd class of $\mathcal{E}$ by the formula $$\text{Td}(\mathcal{E}) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\alpha_k}{(1-e^{-\alpha_k})}.$$

> Is there some hidden representation theory behind the Todd class formula? Is it related to the Weyl character formula?

Comment: Of course such questions can always be fruitful, but, aside from the fact that the denominators can be written in a formally similar form, I don't see much similarity between the two formulæ.  Do you have reason to think that there might be a deeper connection, or is it just curiosity?

Comment: A direct connection between geometry and the Weyl character formula is localisation formula in equivariant cohomology. Not sure if it's directly related to the Todd class.

Comment: This article seems relevant: https://sanathdevalapurkar.github.io/blog/representation-theory/2020/04/30/weyl.html

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11422/what-is-the-hirzebruch-riemann-roch-formula-for-the-flag-variety-of-a-lie-algebr/11440#11440